# Which testing framework in Edulinq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

In Jon Skeet's Edulinq [2nd Blog](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx) he mentioned:

*I've kept the TestExtensions from MoreLINQ, despite NUnit coming with
CollectionAssert.*

Which testing framework he is using as I cannot find "**AssertSequenceEqual"** extension method in NUnit:

```
[Test] 
public void SimpleFiltering() 
{ 
    int[] source = { 1, 3, 4, 2, 8, 1 }; 
    var result = source.Where(x => x < 4); 
    result.AssertSequenceEqual(1, 3, 2, 1); 
}
```

Cannot find the framework of this extension method? Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably something from [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) as your quotation indicates - *"I've kept the TestExtensions from MoreLINQ (...)"*.

Comment: Tried, but this method doesn't seem to be in that framework either. :(

Comment: These are `internal` methods used in morelinq tests - I assume Jon simply copied them to edulinq sources: [AssertSequenceEqual in TestExtensions.cs](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq.Test/TestExtensions.cs)

Comment: Marvelous! You nailed it. Thanks :) +1